# Laravel - Login Laravel - Passowrd HashBytes ('mD5')

Tags: laravel, hash, password-encryption, laravel-10, hashbytes

```
public function masuk(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'USERNAME_ACC'   => 'required',
        'PASSWORD' => 'required'
    ]);
    $username=$request->get('USERNAME_ACC');
    $password=$request->get('PASSWORD');

    // $pass=HASHBYTES('md5',$password);
    // dd($pass);

    

    $cek_user = User::where('USERNAME_ACC',$request->USERNAME_ACC)->where('PASSWORD',\DB::raw("HASHBYTES('md5','$password')"))->count();
    // dd($result->toArray());
    if ($cek_user==0) {
        return redirect('/login')->with('gagal','Username or Password Not Register');
    }else {
        $user=User::where('USERNAME_ACC',$request->USERNAME_ACC)->where('PASSWORD',\DB::raw("HASHBYTES('md5','$password')"))->first();
        if (Auth::guard('web')->login($user))
        {
            return redirect()->intended('admin');
        }
        return "Gagal";
    }
}
```

How can i login with custome Hash in Laravel

i use HashBytes('mD5') for my encryption

So Please Help Me Guyss!!

Comment: What are you having problems with?

Comment: There is already an established authentication/authorization for laravel. You can see Laravel Breeze starter kit.

Comment: How is this problem related to hashes or [tag:hashbytes]?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `config/hashing.php` file and put the one you need, it is responsible for the encoding driver

Comment: are yo have an example fot that?